# AngularJS + ASP.NET MVC - different date formats

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

Hello I have a problem with different date formats between angularjs app and ASP.NET. I have this code in js:

```
$http.post("server/api/save", {date: new Date(2018, 1, 5)}) 
in date is: Fri Jan 05 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100
```

But in server is this: 04.01.2018 23:00:00. In ASP.NET is datatype of date `Nullable<System.DateTime>`.
where would be the problem that the yesterday's date will come to my server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because of day light saving;

```
var date = new Date(2018, 1, 5);
if (date.getTimezoneOffset() == -120) {
    date.setHours(date.getHours() + 1);
}
$http.post("server/api/save", {date: date})
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this doestn work. In server is 4.1 again.

Comment: can be an error in `date.setHours(date.getHours() + 1);`, Sould I change the day?

Comment: No, I put that condition provide example "date.getTimezoneOffset() == -120". You should consider your current time between utc time difference.